# Any way to extract method signature from Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, editor, code-snippets

I want to parse this module `MiniTest::Assertions`,
and get array of string like this:

```
assert(test, msg = nil)

assert_empty(obj, msg = nil)

assert_equal(exp, act, msg = nil)

assert_in_delta(exp, act, delta = 0.001, msg = nil)
```

How can I do that? Any builtin method? gem? Using rdoc?

Comment: You can call parameters on a method object. For instance:
`method(:assert).parameters` 
This will give you the list of params required.